# Error al intentar usar de cordova en Ionic

Tags: android, ionic, cordova

antes que nada saludos. Tengo un problema estoy tratando de hacer una instalación completa de Ionic para empezar a estudiarlo y me va funcionando bien, pero cuando intento hacer

```
ionic cordova build android
```

me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado casi de todo

### 1 - borré node, ionic, cordova, android sdk, android jdk, todo lo que había instalado y reinstalé todo

2 - probé varias configuraciones de las variables de entorno

Variable 1
-- Path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Flash Magic;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;%Android-SDK%\tools;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Variable 2 -- JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201
```

Variable 3 -- ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

Variable 4 -- ANDROID_HOME

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

Allí en ese directorio tengo la instalación del Android SDK

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran ayudar estaría muy agradecido estoy tratando de compilar la aplicacion porque quiero usar el [Scanner de QR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mugh.png) que dice la documentación de Ionic y cuando intento usarlo me dice:

> Error cordova_not_available/

---

Enrique, el error no lo lanza en la pantalla de mi dispositivo si puedes ver lo hace en la consola de Windows desde donde estoy tratando de lanzar el comando. Igual ejecute el comando que me mandaste y me bota el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo lanza en la pantalla de tu dispositivo Android verdad?
Si este es el caso prueba hacer esto:

1. Haber tu emulador Android
2. Corre este comando `ionic cordova emulate android -c` "esto es para tener el modo debug en la consola"
3. Prueba nuevamente

Con esto podrás ver cual es el error exacto que tienes. Tambien verifica si esta bien integrado Native Cordova